# Bug in vendor downloaded via composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I downloaded some dependencies and there is error in vendor. Where should I fix that error? It's bug in transformation from plural to single.

Here's the code I edited in vendor.

```
'sses' => 'ss', // address
'shes' => 'sh', // switch
'lves' => 'lf', // half
'ses' => 's', // basis
```

Comment: You can try to report to package authors. Or if the package is on github, you can fork it, correct it and use your repository clone in [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a VENDOR package has an error you can take several actions:

1) Modify vendor source code (maybe the worst decission) because when you update the package, your source code will be wrong again.

2) Check another version (not DEV) more stable that doesn't have this error.

3) Send the issue to the package owner

4) Make the changes, send a pull request, and be happy contributing to the project :)

5) As the user comment says, you can fork the project (create a copy of vendors project) and correct it. The problem is that you will lost the updates the package owner will done in the future.

I would prefer 4, but that's in your hands.